# How do I hide Banshee?

Tags: music, banshee, indicator-sound

I have just moved from Rhythmbox to Banshee. When I pressed the "close" button on Rhythmbox title bar, the Rhythmbox window disappears, but the application does not close, and I can still listen to music and control it via the sound menu.

Is there any similar way to **hide** (*not* close and *not* minimize) Banshee? I know I can do that by running `banshee --hide`, but I would love to get that result from within Banshee, for example by "closing" it's window. Is that possible? If yes, then how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got to enable the Appindicator Extension.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Dunno why it was disabled, which I haven't noticed.

Answer (score 2):

Newer versions of banshee have a sound menu integration. Activate the MPRIS and the sound menu extension, to get it work.

Eventually you have to install the `banshee-extension-soundmenu` package.

Further information: [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/09/how-to-enable-banshee-sound-menu-integration-in-ubuntu-10-10/)